# What is wrong with this simple implementation of angular-busy?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use "[angular-busy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy)" and it breaks when I add the ['cgBusy'] to the angular module.

Can anyone see what's going wrong with this?  I'm trying to show the loading spinner when data is fetched using the $http service:

```
 $scope.promise = $http({
method: 'JSONP',
url: nprUrl + '&apiKey=' + apiKey + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
}).success(function(data, status) {
  alert('success');
 // Store the list of stories on the scope
 // from the NPR API response object (described above)
 $scope.programs = data.list.story;
}).error(function(data, status) {
 // Some error occurred
 alert('fail');
});
```

Here's my plnker code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wXHdMpiyhHSVTtncorYD?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things

1. You have to include `angular-busy.js` in the `index.html`
2. Your promise is called `promise` not `myPromise`

Working example :

http://plnkr.co/edit/PLCs4S3ih8eD4mQuZOAl?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah I missed the promise/myPromise thing, I had been trying a few things.  Oops forgot the include!  Thank you :)